# p2p direct data exchange...via HTTPS?

Tags: https, p2p, serverless-framework

Is there any protocol, API or software in existence that can send data/IM/etc directly from one device to another with no server?

Can you not use HTTP GET/POST/DELETE directly between two devices when their device data is known to the user(s)?

I would very much like to know if there is ANY software/protocols that can do this.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internet is build on the Internet Protocol suite. This suite has 5 different layers of protocols: The physical layer, the link layer, the network layer, the transport layer and the application layer. Each depends on the one before.

If you just use the browser, by default HTTP (application layer) is used, which relies on TCP (transport layer), which relies on IP (v4 or v6, network layer), which relies on ethernet (link layer), which finally relies on the actual cable that's plugged into your computer (for WiFi, the first three are the same but the last two differ if I'm not mistaken).

Now to your question: `Is there any protocol, API or software in existence that can send data/IM/etc directly from one device to another with no server?`
Yes there is. I suggest you start looking at protocols that are in the [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer). To highlight a few standards next to HTTP(S): FTP is for file transfer, IMAP is for emails clients, SMTP is for email servers and SSH is a secure shell which can also be used to tunnel data through.
For your specific case, I think either FTP ([FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) if you want it over SSL), or SSH can be a solution, but it's hard to know for sure without the specifics.

The only thing that these protocols have in common is that one of the two computers will act like server and the other computer as client. This has as downside that [port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) might be necessary.

---

If you've chosen the protocol you'd like to use, then you're up for the next step, selecting a program that can do that for you. For HTTP(S), I'd recommend Apache. If you're using Linux and chose SSH, then you're in luck, there is a build in SSH server in Linux, you can use that. For other protocols, you might just want to search yourself, as I do not have any suggestions.

I hope this answers most of your questions!
Desirius

Answer (score 0):

In browser context, WebRTC is probably what you are looking for: It allows user to user communications.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC

https://webrtc.org/